# azure webjobs - writing an application vs calling a url

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-webjobs

I have a job I'd like to run on my new Azure hosted web app. In the old pre-Azure days, I would create an .aspx page that did the job, then have some service that simply called the url (www.mysite.com/folder/myjob.aspx) on a schedule.

Is there a better way to do this with webjobs? Can I interact with the actual object model of my site or am I restricted to public URLs and the such?

I've heard I can write a full application (.exe) and host that, but I'm wondering what the advantage of that is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this

1. Azure Worker Roles -Create a console application and then spin this cloud service executes the console app or process. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/fundamentals-introduction-to-azure/
2. Azure Website Jobs - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/

I think website jobs is what you really are looking for. Build a little powershell or EXE of what you want doing then set it on a website job with a schedule. I don't think there is really much advantage either way, if you are already in the azure cloud this is just another service to leverage. We currently use both jobs and worker roles. Worker roles have the advantage of scaling out if needed.